# MSSQL2005: is there a sproc to set the default distribution agent profile?

Tags: sql-server-2005, tsql

I'm trying to work out how to set the default profile for the distribution agent programatically using t-sql. I see there is the [sp_help_agent_profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179923(v=SQL.90).aspx) and [sp_help_agent_default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186339(v=SQL.90).aspx) sprocs which allow you to find out what the default is, but they don't allow you to set it.

Is there a sproc, or should I be directly updating the MSagent_profiles table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. You use something like:

```
exec sp_MSupdate_agenttype_default @profile_id = 14
```

where 14 is the id of the profile you want to set as default. I can't find any documentation for this sproc though, which is weird.